# Ошибка типа данных в xml

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

После десериализации xml документа в виде строки полученной с WCF сервера, **иногда** возникает ошибка

> В документе XML (910, 21) присутствует ошибка.
>
> Message = "", шестнадцатеричное значение 0x0C, является недопустимым
>   знаком., строка 910, позиция 21.

можно как нибудь адекватно обработать данную проблему.

```
XmlSerializer XmlData = new XmlSerializer(typeof(WCF_Client.ProcessInformation));
using (StringReader ReconvertString = new StringReader(Result))
{
    MainForm.ValueProcessInfo.ThreadGettingWCF.Reset();
    WCF_Client.ProcessInformation GetDataContract = (WCF_Client.ProcessInformation)XmlData.Deserialize(ReconvertString);
    MainForm.ValueProcessInfo.ListDataTabControl[_iNdex].ListProcesses = new List<ProcessInfo.ProcessData>();
    for (int i = 0; i < GetDataContract.DataProcessWCF.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Приходящий xml покажите ошибочный

Comment: весь xml файл___

Comment: Но 0x0C действительно является недопустимым символом в XML, покажите хотя бы фрагмент документа где там этот символ. Можно попробовать удалять его из входной строки

Comment: Вот весь файл https://yadi.sk/d/NHr2P0Bq3UN29a